Virtualbox Guru Meditation a critical error has occurred while running the virtual machine

System: Linux Ubuntu 22.04
Suddenly my Virtualbox doesn't work anymore and show this error:
Virtualbox - Guru Meditation
A critical error has occurred while running the virtual machine and the machine execution has been stopped. ...
in Log file I have this errors:
VCPU0: Guru Meditation -37 (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED)
I tried to delete and reinstall the Virtualbox and the OS but it doesn't work.

Thanks to scottgus1 I found the problem:

It appears that KVM/QEMU might be running on the host OS. These block
Virtualbox. They may be enabled by other apps like Docker.

I had the docker running in my system. After disabling the Docker my Virtualbox starts to work.
